# Tilemap gets messed up when converted to hd

Tags: ios, xcode, cocos2d-iphone

I have a floorplan that I need to turn into a tilemap. I'm using the program HD2x to convert my tilemap into an -hd tilemap. I tried it in different ways:

1)I converted the floorplan into a -hd .png with HD2x, and then put this into Tiled, and the saved it and converted the final .tmx file into -hd. I then put the -hd tmx and -hd png file into x-code.

2)I put the regular floorplan into tmx, and then converted this into -hd and converted the floorplan.png into -hd, then put these into x-code.

These aren't working.. either the tilemap is half the size it should be, or it's a QUARTER of the size it should be and the floorplan looks messed up.

Please help.

Comment: You might be using the program wrong. It doesn't make sense that a tool would take an SD image and make it HD. Most likely it is meant to take an HD image and cut its resolution in half for the SD version.

Comment: Why can't a program take a large image and scale it down to half size, making it HD by doubling the resolution?

Comment: From the sounds of your original post it looks like you are taking an image, say 1024x768, and using this program to create a 2048x1536 image. Quality wise that wouldn't make since (see answer below). But regardless if the application has that as an option, check to see that the option is being properly set. That is all based on the impression your OP gave when you stated the tool was converting your resources into -hd, which suggests you are taking SD images and trying to generate HD versions from it.

Answer (score 0):

**Original Comment**

*You might be using the program wrong. It doesn't make sense that a tool would take an SD image and make it HD. Most likely it is meant to take an HD image and cut its resolution in half for the SD version.*

**Answer**

It seems like you are creating images that are half the size of the original, but you are expecting it to do the opposite. In general you wouldn't want to go from SD to HD by simply increasing the image's resolution because the quality would drop. Taking an image and simply doubling its size will not look good.

But quality aside it wouldn't make sense for someone to create an application that increases your resolution for you by simply doubling its size. If that specific application you are using has that as an option, you are likely not setting the right option. From the sounds of it the application is creating images half the size of the images you are feeding it. That is likely the reason why you are getting half or a quarter of the expected size.

Comment: In my response to that, I said "Why can't a program take a large image and scale it down to half size", so I'm expecting an image that is half the size of the original, with double the resolution - not the other way around.

Comment: So what are you talking about then? Your original question stated you had a tile map that you were converting to HD with that app (which means you are increasing the resolution), but then say "either the tilemap is half the size it should be, or it's a QUARTER of the size it should be and the floorplan looks messed up". So if by size you mean resolution, which your question clearly implies, then you can't take an image, cut its resolution in half, and expect it to also have double the resolution. That doesn't make sense. Take 1024 in half = 512. Double 512 and you are back to 1024.

Comment: @AllenS you're misunderstanding him. He is expecting the program to take, say, a 4x4 px image and turn it into an HD 2x2 px image, with double the resolution. This is what is happening, and is not what his problem is. This is expected. He then makes the tilemap with this hd png. Then, when he puts it into x-code, and simulates the app on his phone, on the iPhone screen the map shows up as a half of the size it should be. I.e. he's expecting it to show up as 2x2 px, but it's showing up as 1x1 px on the iphone.

Comment: I'm having the same problem, so maybe it was more obvious to me.

Comment: @AllenS Fewaf is correct. I'm EXPECTING  the map to be at half the size of the original non-hd image. However, it is a quarter of the size, NOT half the size. I'm still having this problem.